# JavaScript Memory Model with Process Memory model

Tags: javascript, memory-management, process

I'm studying Process Memory model and got curious with JavaScript's memory model.

Process Memory model is divided in 5 sections. Code, Data, BSS, Heap, Stack.
I got two questions while studying on it.

First, when javascript get compiled(Just-In-Time compilation), and the process is on cpu and finally it will have those 5 sections of the process. What does BSS do from the sections? BSS is for the global variables with only declaration and not assigned one. Then in the javascript file, if there's some variable without value but declared globally, does it save in BSS? Or is there any other stuff saved in BSS?

Second, what I learned about javascript memory model is, local variables like const, let with primitive dataset is saved in stack, and data types like object, array is saved in heap. What I imagined is, compiled code(from JIT compilation) is saved in code section. Then when we use console of chrome, and create function, where does it save?

I can feel something goes wrong on my mind, and something is wrong, so I want to make it clear but couldn't find answer on it.
So TL;DR:

1. What does process memory model's BSS section save when JavaScript process comes?
2. When we create function from console of chrome devtool, does it save in stack memory?

Comment: I don't think this can be answered in general terms. The exact way memory is used will differ from JavaScript engine to JavaScript engine. V8 (in Chrome, etc.) will be different to JavaScriptCore (in Safari, etc.) which will be different to SpiderMonkey (in Firefox, etc.). Moreover, it can change during the program lifetime, as most engines don't have just a single level of compilation, they do more aggressive optimizing compilation on "hot spots" in the program that are detected as it runs.

Comment: Separately: At least some cases, it's not accurate to say objects are necessarily allocated in the heap. A simple object only used locally that doesn't survive the termination of a function can be allocated on the stack as a performance optimization (at least in V8, at least at some point in its history). (I suspect that was only objects that didn't go through any shape changes and probably other criteria.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Wow, thank you. I guess it's a lot more complicated that I expected. So each engine has different way to optimize javascript process and it's hard to say what's saved in BSS and what will be saved in stack memory because it will be different every time. Guess I have to study more about it. Thank you so much and happy new year!